# Why does my nectarine tree have rotting fruit around seed?

Tags: fruit-trees, plant-health, diseases

My nectarine tree has grown rapidly, it has been a great fruiter, however the fruit is always brown & rotten inside around the seed. Please help!

Answer (score 3):

[Brown Rot of stone fruits](https://www.planetnatural.com/pest-problem-solver/plant-disease/brown-rot/)

Without seeing or knowing more, Brown Rot most certainly could be the culprit. The first and best remedy is cleaning up the ground every fall.  I would also try to remove any 'mummies' left hanging on your tree.

This article discusses spraying and timing of spraying with fungicide.  I have to disagree with this article about the use of a fungicide/pesticide.  Insects are not your problem yet and pesticide is never used as a preventative.  Fungicide is always used for a preventative.  It is like a little raincoat.  Spore + water drop = infection of the entire plant.

Never use 'Tangle Foot' or any sealant on pruning cuts.  Otherwise the information is basic.  Maybe I'll just go find a better article?  I also do not like, "...naturally rather than using toxic chemicals...".  Everything is chemistry. Chemicals can be considered toxic to some plants, yet safe for others.  Bad for humans, bad for insects, safe for plants. Chemistry is chemistry.

Another article on Brown Rot...
[Brown Rot prevention](https://www.starkbros.com/growing-guide/article/all-about-brown-rot)

Comment: Thanks Stormy, I'm not a fan of pesticides so would prefer not to go there. I've no pics as yet as the fruit is still hard on the tree & I'm trying not to disturb them, bruise them or upset then in any way in hope that when they finally ripen they will be healthy though a few have already rotted on the bases

Comment: Cleaning up fruit leaves and debris regularly is the best preventative.  Dormant oils are very sane and very necessary.  You have a disease that is IN your tree and all fruit will be affected. Just takes ONE little spore that we can see only by microscopy. One spore, water hits your tree and your tree is infected.  Cleaning up, getting those mummies off your tree during the late summer, using dormant oils (use a professional spray company...dormant oils are a good thing as you are stopping the spread of spores to other trees)...I'd be pulling all the fruit off if I were you. Dispose carefully.